# How to show tabular data in a nice and practical way

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, user-interface, human-computer-interface

My iOS app is a mobile version of a management program I had developed for a company as a desktop application. So its main tasks are saving data in a database and retrieve them when needed with the option to edit them. So I guess that the GUI is mainly composed by forms to fill in and tables to show data. So I am asking you if you could link me some tutorials or give me some tips on how to realize them in a nice way but not too complex. I'd rather avoid simply creating a blank view controller and inserting labels and text fields without a minimum of criterion. I am very new to iOS and XCode and, as I have not too much time, I am asking directly your opinion instead of spending hours in looking for tutorials.

**UPDATE!**
I mean that I would like to get something similar, for a mobile iOS device, to the following screenshots (from the desktop application I mentioned above)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you need a grid control to do it.
You can develop your own, or use existing library.

I have very good work experience with Infragistic http://www.infragistics.com/products/ios/grids/grid-view-layouts, but maybe DataForm from Telerik will be better in your case http://www.telerik.com/ios-ui/dataform

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm just having a look at them...but I am afraid I can't afford to buy them...isn't there a free way?

Comment: Grid data table - is a business control, and all that I have seen is non-free. As a simple (but not very elegant) solution, you can use a grid table inside WebView. Or, in case if you don't need a lot of features, you can make your own, for example based on UITableView.